# Write index/match loop more efficiently

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a index/match loop to retrieve values from another worksheet (wsNewMV) and populates worksheet wsMvFile. If the value is not in wsNewMV it takes the value from a different column in worksheet wsMvOld. As my code goes column by column and I need to compare 20 columns based on values the code is fairly big.

Any ideas on how I can write the code below more efficient:

```
For i = 2 To y
vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
If IsError(vrw) Then
    vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
        wsMvFile.Range("B" & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(2), vrw)
Else
    wsMvFile.Range("B" & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(3), vrw, 1)
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To y
vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
If IsError(vrw) Then
    vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
        wsMvFile.Range("C" & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(3), vrw)
Else
    wsMvFile.Range("C" & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(5), vrw, 1)
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To y
vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
If IsError(vrw) Then
    vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
        wsMvFile.Range("D" & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(4), vrw)
Else
    wsMvFile.Range("D" & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(6), vrw, 1)
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To y
vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
If IsError(vrw) Then
    vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
        wsMvFile.Range("E" & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(5), vrw)
Else
    wsMvFile.Range("E" & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(7), vrw, 1)
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To y
vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
If IsError(vrw) Then
    vrw = Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
        wsMvFile.Range("F" & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(6), vrw)
Else
    wsMvFile.Range("F" & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(8), vrw, 1)
End If
Next i
```

Note that the that wsMvFile.Range will range from A to U, the wsMvOld.Columns range from 1 column to 21 column and only the wsNewMV.Columns range will be different depending on what column is pulled.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Efficient as in lines of code, or efficient as in performance?

Comment: Lines of code please. The code run fairly fast already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start would be to extract all of the common code out into it's own `Sub`:

```
Private Sub AppropriateName(wsMvFile As Worksheet, wsMvOld As Worksheet, wsNewMV As Worksheet, _
                            rowCount As Long, workCol As String, _
                            srcCol1 As Integer, srcCol2 As Integer)
    Dim vrw As Variant, i As Long

    For i = 2 To rowCount
        vrw = Application.match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewMV.Columns(2), 0)
        If IsError(vrw) Then
            vrw = Application.match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
                wsMvFile.Range(workCol & i) = Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(srcCol1), vrw)
        Else
            wsMvFile.Range(workCol & i) = Application.Index(wsNewMV.Columns(srcCol2), vrw, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then you can just call it with the appropriate parameters:

```
AppropriateName wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, y, "B", 2, 3
AppropriateName wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, y, "C", 3, 5
AppropriateName wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, y, "D", 4, 6
AppropriateName wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, y, "E", 5, 7
AppropriateName wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, y, "F", 6, 8
```

Ideally, that would go in it's own loop, but since the last parameter skips the number 4, you'd have to do some sort of lookup. That should at least give a start on refactoring.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response Comintern. This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: @VBAPete - For stuff like this you can cheat a little bit - I'll shamelessly plug the [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) VBA add-in.  It can automatically extract functions.

Answer (score 1):

the following is a very short (and fast) solution

```
Sub doit(curMVSht As Worksheet, oldMVSht As Worksheet, newMVSht As Worksheet, curShtCol As String, oldShtCol As Long, newShtCol As Long)

curMVSht.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, Columns(curShtCol).Column - 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & newMVSht.name & "!C" & newShtCol & ",MATCH(RC1," & newMVSht.name & "!C2,0))," _
      & " IFERROR(INDEX(" & oldMVSht.name & "!C" & oldShtCol & ",MATCH(RC1," & oldMVSht.name & "!C1,0))," _
      & " """"))"

End Sub
```

it's actually a single statement I broke into three lines for readability purposes only, and you can call it as

```
doit wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, "B", 2, 3
doit wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, "C", 3, 5
doit wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, "D", 4, 6
doit wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, "E", 5, 7
doit wsMvFile, wsMvOld, wsNewMV, "F", 6, 8
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution user3598756.

Comment: you're welcome .this should match your "Lines of code" optimization neds